# Zend Framework 2 - Updating Zend causes RuntimeException

Tags: php, zend-framework2, updates, composer-php

I updated my `composer.json` to get the new version of `ZF2`.

Unfortunately I get this error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Failed to clone http://github.com/zendframework/zf2.git via git, https and
>   http protocols, aborting.

Any ideas what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found it [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Framework-2-0-0rc6-Released-tp4656578p4656582.html).

I'll post it anyway because it's kinda hard to find via Google.

You have to remove the `vendor/zendframework` directory in the project to get `composer` to do what you want.